# Sharepoint - Delete item from recycle

Tags: sharepoint

Recently i came across with the following scenario:

1. Create a list item in custom list
2. Delete it using the batch deletion procedure (before delete it keep the UniqueId somewhere)
3. The item goes to the recycle bin
4. I have tried the web.RecycleBin.Delete(ids) (i used the UniqueId from step 2) and the error System.ArgumentException: ids at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.GetSortedIds(Guid[] ids, SPRecycleBinItemType[]& itemTypes) occurred
5. I  tried to iterate through the recycle bin items and none of the deleted items had the UniqueId from step 2. Also i tried the SPRecycleBinItemCollection.GetItemById without any luck

my question is what guid expects the web.RecycleBin.Delete? I used the  item.UniqueId but i think i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, you can try the following code. You can store the guid in a temp Array.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strSiteUrl))//SPContext.Current.Site)
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {

                    // Allow Unsafe Updates to prevent the cross site scripting
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    //// Get The SPList
                    SPList list = web.Lists["123"];
                    // Get the list items

                    SPListItem item = list.Items[0];
                    Guid strGuid = item.UniqueId;
                    item.Delete();

                    Guid[] guids = { strGuid };
                    web.RecycleBin.Delete(guids);
                }

            }
```

But I suggest you to use the CSOM to do it.